# LNK1104 for unneeded library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, openframeworks

I am trying to include the Boost Library in my OpenFrameworks project, in particular it is 
When I add the boost root directory to the `Additional Include Directories` of a new project, I see the error `LNK1104  cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_72.lib'`, although I don't even need the filesystem library.

However, when I added the boost root directory to the `Additional Include Directories` of a freshly create c++ console project, the error does not show, and I can make use of the library without problems.

Runtime Library is /MDd.

What might cause this problem? A broken build of boost?

One

Comment: Are you sure that the openframeworks project does not include a header from the filesystem library? That would be my first guess where the dependency exists.

Comment: @drescherjm But wouldn't it show an error when I did not add boost to additional included directories?

Comment: That is strange, Perhaps there is a filename conflict between a current header from some other library in your project and one of the headers in the boost filesystem library. Although if that was the case I would expect compiler errors. Was boost root added to the end of the `Additional Include Directories` or the beginning?

Comment: At the beginning. I have moved it to the end and now the project builds! Please post your comment as a response so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the comments to the question. Although this is unusual it could be that a header in one of the dependencies of your project has the same name as a header in the filesystem library. And since you put boost first in the `Additional Include Directories` the boost header was included instead of a header from a different library. By default with `Visual Studio` boost automatically inserts link commands using a `#pragma comment(lib, libname)` so including this header will cause a link dependency.

A solution to try in this case is to move boost to the end of the `Additional Include Directories` so when the compiler searches for the header it will find the one from the previous dependency first.